# Storing value in Session in Thread in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, web

I'm pretty new to MVC so forgive me if I'm missing anything.

In one of my controllers, I initiate a class that does some processing and outputs a string like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(string reg)
{
    string sCarmodel;
    GetRegInfo gri = new GetRegInfo(reg, out sCarmodel);
    Session["test"] = sCarmodel;

    return View("Check");
}
```

So far so good, and the output of sCarmodel is correctly stored in Session where it can be accessed later in the View. However, I need to put the class in a separate thread, since it takes some time to finish it and I want to return the View aschyncronosly. So I tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(string reg)
{
    var getreginfoThread = new Thread(
        () =>
        {
            string sCarmodel;
            GetRegInfo gri = new GetRegInfo(reg, out sCarmodel);
            Session["test"] = sCarmodel;
        }
        );

    getreginfoThread.Start();

    return View("Check");
}
```

I know that I can store the value of "sCarmodel" in a database from within the class itself, but I was looking for a way to skip using a database. Using a thread, the value of sCarmodel is not stored in Session, and the Session is `null` later when I try to retrieve it.

Can anybody offer some advice on how I can access a value from a Class while in a thread?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Problem solved, thanks everybody for their suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by storing an instance of the class in TempData. Also, instead of Thread, I use Task which is much better. Here is my solution:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetRegInfo(string reg)
        {
            var gri = new GetRegInfo(reg);
            TempData["GetRegInfo"] = gri;

            Action<object> action = (object obj) => gri.Start();
            var t1 = new Task(action, "GetRegInfo");   
            t1.Start();

            return View("bilforsakring");
        }
```

Later I use a JavaScript timer with Ajax and get the value like this:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
        public ActionResult GetRegInfoAjax()
        {
            if (TempData["GetRegInfo"] != null)
            {
                var g = (GetRegInfo)TempData["GetRegInfo"];  
                return Content(g.sCarmodel);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("null");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Put an custom object in Session during processing of a request.

Pass a reference to this custom object to the background thread.

Set a property of the custom object in your background thread.

Make sure you do any necessary synchronization.

Comment: Works for me. Simple and elegant! Don't know about thread-safety but it's an easy solution and finally works after having tried all kinds of different things :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow pass the session to the background thread. See [here](http://info.titodotnet.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-3-accessing-session-inside.html) for example.

By the way, why aren't you using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)?

Comment: What advanted does Task Pararell Library have compared to the approach I am using?

Comment: You'll be using the thread-pool, which is better suited for short tasks you run in parallel. You can use the thread-pool without TPL, but why not switch to a modern API while you're at it?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's not that the value is not stored in Session. It is. The problem is your code continues execution in parallel to the thread your created, and when it is accessing the `Session["test"]` it is not yet assigned by your thread.</strike>  You have to reorganize your code somehow. Also, it is not recomended to launch threads in asp.net application, as it is very resource intensive.

**EDIT**

It seems that it really doesnt set the Session variable. If you really want to do it this way, you can use `CallContext` for that:

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("CurrentSession", Session);

var getreginfoThread = new Thread(
    () =>
    {
        string sCarmodel;
        GetRegInfo gri = new GetRegInfo(reg, out sCarmodel);
        var session = (HttpSessionState)CallContext.LogicalGetData("CurrentSession");

        session["test"] = sCarmodel;
    }
    );

getreginfoThread.Start();

return View("Check");
```

You would have to somehow wait for this data not to be null and then get it using `Session["test"]`

Comment: Well, I'm using a timer to check Session["test"] every 5 seconds. It's always null, even when the background thread finishes.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working for me. CallContext.LogicalGetData("test") is always null :/

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when doing session["test"] = sCarmodel; or session["test"] = "test";

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext the parent/owner object of Session object is not transported to new threads, therefore your Session is not accessible in threads other than the main one.

I suggest that you return sCarmodel from your thread using async/await and set it to your Session in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you not to use Session object in threads as it is not thread safe. In ASP.NET each request has its own thread and its own session.

You never described a real problem (unfortunately) so I don't really know what you are trying to solve, but spinning up a new thread manually and putting data in Session is not a solution anyway.

If you want to do things asynchronously to let the web server serve other clients while doing something in background, then look perhaps at the asynchronous controllers:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Again, it would be really useful to know what is it you try to achieve to suggest a proper solution.

Comment: I have solved my problem by storing a reference of the class in TempData. Seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I need to put the class in a separate thread, since it takes some time to finish it and I want to return the View aschyncronosly.

Wrong. This is the completely *wrong* way to solve this problem. In an ASP.NET application, you should never return when there is more work to do unless you have already saved that work to persistent storage.

Keeping the work in memory (i.e., with a thread or task) is an incorrect solution.

The correct solution is to use persistent storage (e.g., Azure Queue, MSMQ, or WebSphere MQ) to store the work to be done and then have a separate service which reads that queue, takes the appropriate action, and stores the results in another persistent data structure. You can then have the client poll (e.g., HTTP request) the "result" data structure and/or notify the client (e.g., SignalR) when the result is saved.

I go into more details [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html), and also have some example code to use there if you are *absolutely* sure that you want to take the unsafe route.

Comment: Talk about making assumptions. The process takes 3-4 seconds and it only returns ONE string. Do you think I would go through all that trouble for something like that? lol...

Comment: Did you read my blog post? Or the one it links to by Phil Haack that talks about how dangerous it is? We're talking about semantic correctness here. If you don't care to do it right, then just do the easy thing and finish the processing before returning the result.